# scroll rotate image working only one image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a rotate img width window scroll. But i have one problem. The problem is only one image will rotating. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/JoNgpy)** from codepen.io

If you click the demo then you can see when you scroll down then only one image rotating other image not rotating. I want to make it when scrolling down then all image will rotate. How can i do that anyone can help me ?

```
<div class="container">
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gear2.svg" alt id="leftgear">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gear2.svg" alt id="leftgear">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gear2.svg" alt id="leftgear">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gear2.svg" alt id="leftgear">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/gear2.svg" alt id="leftgear">
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var theta = $(window).scrollTop() / 10 % Math.PI;
$('#leftgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + theta + 'rad)' });
});
```

Comment: IDs must be UNIQUE. Use a class and .each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs must be unique. Change ID to class and do

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var theta = $(window).scrollTop() / 10 % Math.PI;
  $('.leftgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + theta + 'rad)' });
});
```

or if you need each to change differently

```
  $('.leftgear').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({ transform: 'rotate(' + (theta+(i*10)) + 'rad)' });
  });
```

Comment: Ok, Now I know what you meant :) I suspected that OP wants to have also `.rightgear`, so that `each` would be unnecessary :)